# customizing moderncv \section title style

Tags: sectioning, formatting, moderncv

I would like to customize `\section` style in order to have 
the following title (forget the horizontal line) :

[image: title \section]

I imagine that I need to modify the following definition:

```
\renewcommand*{\section}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \strut\sectionstyle{#1}%
  {\color{color1}\hrule}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}
```

The code I am using is:

```
\section{CORE COMPETENCIES}
```

Can you tell me how?

Comment: Excuse me! Is it ok, now?

Comment: no need to apologize :-) Yes, it's OK now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possibility using `\colorbox` and a `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{\colorbox{color1}{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\sectionfont#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\section}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \strut\sectionstyle{#1}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\section{CORE COMPETENCIES}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps this modification follows more accurately the image in the question (no horizontal space between the colored box and the text and bold-faced text); I also added `\MakeUppercase` to `\sectionstyle`:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionfont{\bfseries\large}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
  \colorbox{color1}{%
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\sectionfont\rule[-.5ex]{0pt}{2.8ex}\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}}
\renewcommand*{\section}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \sectionstyle{#1}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\section{Core competencies}

\end{document}
```

[image]